# Redirection to previous page after login with URL only

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Let's say I want the system work like this: when visitor goes to page "test1" or "test2" he would be redirected to sign-up/login form and once the form submitted successfully, the visitor would be  redirected to the page he tried to access previously (test1 or test2). Is it possible to achieve this if I only have a URL field for redirection in login/sign-up form?

I am on WP 4.9.6, with Ultimate Member plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
if ( wp_get_referer() )
{
    wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
}
else
{
    wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the result of Your code by the URL string instead? For example when visitor goes to mywebsite.com/test1.php he would be redirected to login for (till this part all is ok), and once submitted, redirected by something like mywebsite.com/?redirectafterlogin=login.php. Because I can only use URL address in this case, no php code, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for such plugin. And also, for example when I go to the "test1" page I am being redirected to URL as follows: `https://mywebsite.com/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Ftest1%2F`
So I wonder is there any string that could be used instead of "...%2Ftest1%2F..." so I could request the previous page url automatically (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so solution was easier than expected.

Simply I had to go to Ultimate-Member -> User Roles, choose whichever role I need and then set the "Action after login" to "Redirect to URL" and leave that field blank. As shown in here: http://prntscr.com/jq69dq

Comment: As per the UM documentation [here](https://ultimatemember.com/php-docs/) , its in fact using the same method I mentioned, but within the plugin itself. Code snippet from their page:

`um_dynamic_login_page_redirect()

um_dynamic_login_page_redirect(string  $redirect_to = '') : boolean|false|mixed|string|void

Get where user should be headed after logging
Parameters
string  $redirect_to  
Returns
boolean|false|mixed|string|void`